# Installing cmake with home-brew

Tags: cmake, homebrew

I'm new to programming. Can you please help me install cmake? I typed `brew install cmake`. What should I do next?

Comment: that should do the job, you already ran the command to install it.

Comment: after install run command like this "./{{output_app_file}}"

Answer (score 176):

Typing `brew install cmake` as you did installs `cmake`. Now you can type `cmake` and use it.

If typing `cmake` doesn’t work make sure `/usr/local/bin` is your `PATH`. You can see it with `echo $PATH`. If you don’t see `/usr/local/bin` in it add the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Then reload your shell session and try again.

---

(all the above assumes Homebrew is installed in its default location, `/usr/local`. If not you’ll have to replace `/usr/local` with `$(brew --prefix)` in the `export` line)

Answer (score 62):

1. Download the latest CMake Mac binary distribution here: https://cmake.org/download/
   (current latest is: https://cmake.org/files/v3.17/cmake-3.17.1-Darwin-x86_64.dmg)
2. Double click the downloaded .dmg file to install it. In the window that pops up, drag the CMake icon into the Application folder.
3. Add this line to your .bashrc file: `PATH="/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin":"$PATH"`
4. Reload your .bashrc file: `source ~/.bashrc`
5. Verify the latest cmake version is installed: `cmake --version`
6. You can launch the CMake GUI by clicking on LaunchPad and typing cmake. Click on the CMake icon that appears.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: While this works, this is not the correct answer because it doesn’t use Homebrew- which OP explicitely mentioned. Also, the downside of this method is you have to upgrade `cmake` by yourself instead of having it for free with `brew upgrade`.

Answer (score 26):

On MacBooks with M1 processor:

##### Install:

```
arch -arm64 brew install cmake
```

##### Upgrade:

```
arch -arm64 brew upgrade cmake
```

Comment: A great update for Apple M1 users. Thank you.