# Build OpenCV for iOS fail

Tags: python, ios, opencv, cmake

I downloaded OpenCV folder from GitHub and followed the ReadMe instruction to build it for ios.
After use `python opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py ios` command I have the following error:

```
Executing: ['cmake', '-GXcode', '-DAPPLE_FRAMEWORK=ON', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DIOS_ARCH=armv7', '-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/name/Downloads/opencv/platforms/ios/cmake/Toolchains/Toolchain-iPhoneOS_Xcode.cmake', '-DENABLE_NEON=ON', '/Users/name/Downloads/opencv', '-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fembed-bitcode', '-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fembed-bitcode'] in /Users/name/Downloads/ios/build/build-armv7-iphoneos
============================================================
ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
============================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 112, in build
    self._build(outdir)
  File "opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 104, in _build
    self.buildOne(t[0], t[1], mainBD, cmake_flags)
  File "opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 186, in buildOne
    execute(cmakecmd, cwd = builddir)
  File "opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 36, in execute
    retcode = check_call(cmd, cwd = cwd)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 535, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What I have to do to fix it?

Comment: It seems that you moved your files around but forgot to update the paths in the command. Did you copy files in/out of folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone in the future will have the same problem.
This problem was in the master branch, downloading branch 2.4 and adding CMake at PATH the build process go well

Comment: Could you please explain what "adding CMake at PATH" means? In context of this instruction. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html

I've downloaded "branch 2.4" but can't understand what to do next =( Sorry for dummy question and thank.

Comment: @ZevsVU https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185079/installing-cmake-with-home-brew

Comment: I build many times. Terrible with any solution. Maybe the master branch is really bad for build.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem.
In the master branch or 3.4 branch or 2.4 branch.
But after installing cmake, it will be fine.

In the 2.4 branch error message will show :

`/bin/sh: cmake: command not found`